# How to test #call method in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am having sth like this:

```
it "test" do
    obj = MyObj.new
    invoker = MyInvoker.new(obj)
    expect(obj).to receive(:bar)
    invoker.invoke
end



#My tested code
class MyObj
  def bar
  end
end

class MyInvoker
   def initialize obj
       @obj = obj
   end

   def invoke
     method = @obj.method(:bar)
     method.call
   end
end
```

I want to test if method :bar is being called. However, my expect keep telling me obj just receive :bar 0 time.

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: You need to write `meth=double` then write `expect(obj).to receive(:method).with(:bar).and_return(meth) ` and then `expect(meth).to receive(:call) `. Put these three lines before calling invoke in your test. There is also a better way. If you change the invoke method and use `@obj.bar` your test should pass

Comment: you  should just write this as an answer @RadaBogdan

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Your example works just fine for me (the test passes). Besides, I don't see any reason why this should not work.

Comment: @Stefan how about a = [1,2]
        m = a.method(:first)
        expect(a).to receive(:first)
        m.call

Comment: @DongLong you have to move `expect(a).to receive(:first)` before `a.method(:first)`.